# Can I stop total line clearing when backspacing on a read in Bash?

Tags: bash, tput

I have a Bash script which asks a user to input text. It displays the question and answer within a line-drawing character menu 'panel', like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
function menu_display {
clear
tput cup 0 0; tput sgr0; echo " ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐"
tput cup 1 0; tput sgr0; echo " │                                                           │"
tput cup 2 0; tput sgr0; echo " │                                                           │"
tput cup 3 0; tput sgr0; echo " │                                                           │"
tput cup 4 0; tput sgr0; echo " │                                                           │"
tput cup 5 0; tput sgr0; echo " │                                                           │"
tput cup 6 0; tput sgr0; echo " │                                                           │"
tput cup 7 0; tput sgr0; echo " ╘═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╛"
}

function ask_question {
menu_display
tput cup 3 3; tput sgr0; echo "Type some text here: "
tput cup 3 24; read -e -r INPUT_TEXT;
}

ask_question

exit 0
```

Everything looks and works fine to start with -until the user types some text and then hits the backspace key to delete/edit/correct it. Backspacing works correctly to start with, as characters from the end to the second character typed are erased. But if the backspace key is pressed to delete the first character typed at the prompt, the cursor jumps back to the beginning of the line and the vertical line-drawing characters and the question prompt is lost entirely. (At least, it does on current Manjaro using KDE with either Konsole or Xterm). The user is left attempting to type a correct answer to a question that is no longer displayed (and quite possibly not remembered!)

Is there a way to either:

1. Detect when a user backspaces on the first character and thus re-draw and re-display the menu_display and question prompt when it can be presumed that the originals have vanished; or
2. Totally prevent the user backspacing on the first character typed by way of response, thus preserving the question prompt from "backspace erasure", whilst still giving the user the ability to correct the first character typed in some way; or
3. Allowing the user to backspace erase the first typed character, but preventing the cursor at that point from jumping to the beginning of the line, thus preserving the original question prompt; or
4. A better way of doing this entirely? (I don't want to use ncurses or dialog, however, as this would be the only point in a long bash script where such tools would be used, and I'm trying to keep external dependencies down to a minimum)

Note that there is no limit to the length of user input expected, so a user's answers could well wrap onto a second line, if that was going to affect any suggested solutions.

Would appreciate any pointers, if they exist!

Comment: For #4, not wanting a border around the text seems like a hugely superior approach.

Comment: But doesn't answer the question -and the border in any case makes no difference. If the prompt disappears (which it does), the disappearance of the border is a minor matter. Edit the menu_display function to remove everything except the command 'clear', for example: the fundamental problem of disappearing prompts persists.

Comment: More generally not messing with curses and just letting `read` do whatever it does is what I would recommend. Take out all the `tput` stuff or give up on the requirement to not use a proper curses library (in which case probably also take out all the `tput` stuff and replace it with whatever the library provides instead).

Comment: Again, points taken, but they don't answer the question, but only to workaround. If "read whatever it does" cannot restrict things in the way I'd like, I potentially have no choice. But I'm asking if there *are* ways to fix the actual issue asked about, rather than dodging it. Hoping someone else may have insight.

Comment: Indeed, these are "comments", not "answers".

Comment: Well, I'm after an answer :) I don't mind the answer being "It can't be done". But I'd rather the entire premise of the question wasn't re-written! No offence intended, and I appreciate the input.

Comment: The thing is that it is not related to bash. Bash doesn't really care about what is displayed or erased. Bash (or its ancestor) was ok back in the time when displays ran on a printer, and nothing could be erased. From bash point of view there is a standard output, and what happens to what is pushed there is none of its concern. Tput is a tool that output strange characters to that output, knowing that it will probably behave in a given way (if the terminal using that output understand correctly those control characters).

Comment: For example, you can see the exact same behavior with python. Just try ``print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r", end='')`` type a few thing then backspace in the following prompt.

Comment: My guess (but I never investigate) is that it is a ``readline``  behavior. And, ``-e`` option of means precisely "use readline" (which gives some advantage, such as possibility to go up and history of previous input with arrows)

Comment: I did try removing the -e and did assorted other experiments with read options, but it appeared to make no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Well I've just tried your code without the ``-e`` and it does make a difference. So, if that doesn't work for you, you need to update your minimal reproducible example, since the one you gave doesn't work with ``-e`` and does work without.

Comment: Yup. Turns out that I may have added, removed and fiddled with all sorts of switches without specifically singling out the -e. Just saw your answer: it works, so I've accepted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I continue my comments in a proper answer, since it might be acceptable to you.
As I was saying, this is a readline behaviour, not a bash behaviour.
Readline is the librarie used by almost all commandline tools (such as interactive interpreter, like python, node, bash, ...)

A way around it may be to loose the `-e` flag you pass to read. Which precisely means "use readline to read".

Of course, it has a drawback: no more completion or history, or any perk like that that readline offers

Comment: Well, I mentioned above that I'd removed the -e switch, plus added and removed assorted others in attempt to get something to work, and had concluded that none of it worked. I was wrong. I just removed the -e again and it now does precisely what I need it to do! Many thanks. Answer accepted.